# Split() function in python changes special characters

Tags: python, split, character

When I split a string containing special (unknowns) characters such as new emojis (this one for instance --- > ""), Python will return it to me this way --> "\U0001f972".

`s = " "`
`liste = s.split()`
`print(liste)`

This returns `['\U0001f972', '\U0001f972']` but I need `['', '']`

How could I make so ?

Comment: Please share your code, how you are splitting the string.

Comment: Are you certain its changing the values and its not just whatever's printing it like cmd is changing it?

Comment: It might help you to google "\U0001f972" and dig a little bit into what's going on there (after you've done that check out my name and pfp)

Comment: string.encode('utf-8').decode('unicode-escape') --- see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56629083/how-to-convert-a-string-variable-with-special-characters-in-python-to-print-prop --- hopefully this works

Comment: if I use `print("\U0001f972")` then I get on screen  - so it is correct character in terminal but you may need to use `print()` to see it correctly. If you use `print(repr("\U0001f972"))` then you get `"\U0001f972"` and this is how may work Python shell, Jupyter, etc if you don't use `print()`.

Comment: Thank you for your consideration. I've updated the post to make it more clear. All solutions proposed above unluckily didn't do the job. Any more ideas ?